# What does it mean that block is irreversible

Tags: block-producer, mainnet, blocks, irreversible, irreversible-state

I mean there are block producers and there are currently just 21 TRUSTED ones.

1. Why do we need to wait for 15/21 to fully "confirm" transaction?
2. Because that means sometimes almost 3-4 minutes. Isn't it safe to consider the transaction as confirmed after 1-2 confirmations by BP?
3. How can the transaction be reversed? Were there any cases of this action?

Answer (score 2):

You must wait for a block height to be lower than the current Last Irreversible Block (also known as LIB) to be considered irreversible. With the quick speed of the network, it is common to see microforks that occur - often when ProducerB starts producing its schedule off of Block 11 of ProducerA's round. This can happen due to latency conditions because of the hops between the two nodes. 
There are other things that could be at play, but suffice to say that a transaction, while once in a block can be seen as having a high degree of confidence of being part of the blockchain, cannot be seen as irreversible *until* it has been passed by LIB.